# how to add .so file in android source code build in ASOP

Tags: android, build-process, android-source, android-make

I just want to know how to install application in system folder during build source code with .so file .
I have put .apk file in system folder but confuse where to place .so file . Then after we build source code with make command . 
I want to know the directory , path and setting for .so file in ASOP.

Comment: Confused about your question, is that .so file part of your application? Then it should be in the apk file not anywhere else. But what is it related with AOSP?

Comment: Actually i have to build tablet source code for flashing in which the particular apk file install so that user can't uninstall it. i have apk file and .so file of particular application. The apk file are placed in vendor folder and entries are placed in android.mk file . But for .so file i don't know .I just want to know that how .so file install manually in android .

Answer (score 0):

Try placing in /system/lib/ folder